# td click not being registered by jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to open a modal window based on a td click in jQuery. Doesn't seem to be firing. I've looked over my code and it all definitely seems correct. What could I be doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () { <? php
      for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) { ?> $("td#grid2_mon<?php echo $i ?>").click(function () {
              $("#search_dialogMon<?php echo $i ?>").dialog({
                  modal: true,
                  height: 400,
                  width: 400,
                  buttons: {
                      Close: function () {
                          $(this).dialog("close");
                      }
                  }
              });
          }); <? php
      } ?>
  }
</script>
<?php 
  for ($i=1 ; $i <=9 ; $i++) { ?>
    <div id="search_dialogMon<?php echo $i ?>" style="display:none"></div>
<?php } ?>

<table>
<tr id="grid2_mon">
    <td class="gridSide">Mon</td>
    <td class="box" id="grid2_mon1">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="box" id="grid2_mon2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="box" id="grid2_mon3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="box" id="grid2_mon4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="box" id="grid2_mon5">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="box" id="grid2_mon6">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="box" id="grid2_mon7">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="box" id="grid2_mon8">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="box" id="grid2_mon9">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like a parse error at the end of the first script block. `}` should probably be `});` Might be more issues, but that one stands out. Do you know how to debug javascript? Familiar with Chrome/IE developer tools or Firebug?

Comment: I "hand-executed" the php, and apart from the syntax error the JavaScript code runs fine. And I second the suggestion of using a debugger, Chrome's console would have easily shown the problem.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hpFby

Comment: Your code appears fine. I would try to take the output of your PHP (i.e., your js/html) and run it through jsfiddle or jshint. I ran your code and it worked fine. http://jsfiddle.net/yFA45/1/

Comment: you should consider separating your js and your PHP, its a lot easier to spot whats wrong with the code. http://jsfiddle.net/B34Hx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
your coding is not done properly you have made many syntax errors please try this code this will help you    
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js">    </script>`    `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js">      </script>`
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $("td ").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#search_dialogMon"+id).dialog({height: 400,width:500,modal: true,    
        buttons: [{text: "OK",click: function() {$( this ).dialog( "close" );}}]
    });
    }); 
});
</script>
<?php 
for ($i=1 ; $i <=9 ; $i++) { ?>
<div id="search_dialogMon<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none">testing no<?php echo $i;?> </div>
<?php } ?>
<table>
<tr id="">
<td class="gridSide">Mon</td>
<?php 
for ($i=1 ; $i <=9 ; $i++) 
{ 
?>
<td class="box" id="<?php echo $i; ?>">mon<?php echo $i; ?></td>
<?php
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```